# Hibernate - Spring Data JPA One To Many unique constraint across table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I have a department and employee table. I need the dept name and employees in the department to be unique such that a new entry for the dept with the same set of employees is given it should throw a unique constraint violation error.

I am not sure how to work this out in hibernate.

I need to have unique constraints across multiple tables.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(
        name="dept"
)
public class DeptEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dep", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Employee> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

  }
```

import javax.persistence.*;

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="emp"
  )
  public class Employee {


      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private int id;

      private String name;


      @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
      private DeptEntity dep;

  }
```

Comment: you probably need to use a db trigger for this

Comment: No solution using JPA ?
Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like :

```
@Column(unique= true)
private String name;
```

Comment: Uniqueness check across multiple tables is the question.
Thank you for the attempt

Comment: Some questions ! you sead : "for the dept with the same set of employees is given it should throw a unique constraint violation error" , so if it's not the same set of employees do you allow persistance ? if you sead yes , so your relation would be many to many with a compound constraint on dep and emp (In the many to many table) . Otherwise, if you sead no , i think you just need to put a unique constraints on dept name and that's all . Tell me if that's okay ^^ @unnik